# Live usb/cd is not booting on Asus M599X evo motherboard having UEFI bios?

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, uefi

I tried booting both x32 and x64 versions of ubuntu 12.04.
When i choose Default/Try ubuntu without installing in the boot menu option, the system hangs and the booting stops.

Comment: If u could see "try Ubuntu" or "install Ubuntu", then your system is booted and loaded the live media.Please include your system RAM and from where u downloaded the ISO,have u looked the md5sum of it etc here when u reply.

Comment: I have a different asus laptop and also having problem booting 12.04.  Not sure if it is the same cause.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/126149/inconsistent-booting-problem-12-04lts-on-asus-u46e-ral7

Comment: I have downloaded the iso from ubuntu official website, it is a desktop version.
I have checked the md5 and it is same. My system ram is 8GB DDR3.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access a boot options screen. Most firmwares let you do this by pressing F2, F10, F12, or some other key at boot time. (Look for a prompt about this or consult your manual.) With any luck, you'll see two options for how to boot your CD, one in BIOS mode and one in EFI/UEFI mode. They aren't likely to be labelled this logically, though; you might see something like "Boot CD" and "Boot CD (UEFI shell)". Try both of those options. It's possible that your board is having problems with whichever mode it's selecting by default, but that the other one will work.