# ubuntu 12.04 boot once every two/three times

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, asus

I installed ubuntu 12.04 in an Asus 8gbram i7 sharing drive with windows 7.

tried many options as setnomode, ro, ro quiet, deleting msdos6 and replacing it with6 at set root=(hd0,6) was appearing as set root=(hd0,msdos6) at booting time and get crazy try many combinations 
I realized that the problem is that even the same options get sometimes to boot, 
sometimes to a purple screen 
and sometimes to a smtp message and gets freezed there.

in my bios i have uefi disabled as it was by default in this machine.

dmesg for error just this line when im able to boot:

```
EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

Also Im quite suprised as i was expecting the installation to go smooth and suddenly menu.lst is deprecated and my knowledge is old.

Anyone facing/faced similar behaviour?

found this answer [Inconsistent booting problem 12.04LTS on Asus U46E RAL7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126149/inconsistent-booting-problem-12-04lts-on-asus-u46e-ral7)
and solved the problem, just turn of vt-d from the BIOS

Comment: That sounds more like a hardware problem if it is booting some times and not others.

Comment: its always arriving to the grub, if i choose windows theres never a problem