# Ubuntu 13.10 Compatible with an Asus U46e-bal6?

Tags: 13.10, asus, compatibility

If I remember correctly, the 12 series of Ubuntu had some issues with the Asus U46e-bal6 -- how is 13.10 working, anyone know?

I'm starting to have some issues with Windows 7, and I have no desire to upgrade to Windows 8.  Giving serious consideration to returning to a dual boot set up with Ubuntu.  Anything I should know going in with my current hardware?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the hardware built into the laptop, I see no issues.

Some people reported boot problems caused by the VT-d feature, which can be resolved (according to [this answer here on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/351945/215352)) by either using `noapic` as a boot parameter or just disabling VT-d in the BIOS.

If you have doubts about the general performance of Ubuntu on your laptop, I'd highly recommend [creating a bootable USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and giving the live system a spin.

Comment: Thanks, DRC, I appreciate the feedback.  I had heard about the noapic issue, but there were also some instances of cooling fans not turning off and a few other items.  I'll look into it a little further, and I'll try the bootable USB.